# Change UDP IP address

Tags: networking, proxy, udp, webrtc

I'm trying to hide my WebRTC IP to a proxy server(x.x.x.x:yy) that I use to hide my identity, when I go to [Ipleak](https://ipleak.com/) I can see that my real IP is revealed. when I use common VPN services out there, not only I can change my IP to the proxy IP, it also changes(not hiding) my WebRTC IP to the proxy IP, in other words, both my UDP and TCP connections are going to have the same IP address. there are some browser extensions out there that can successfully hide my real IP, also, I can disable WebRTC which will cause the IP go away, which is not exactly what I want. I want to CHANGE it and not to hide it, just like VPN services do.

I find out I need something like port forwarding, I suppose I need something to listen and rewrite all UDP packets to go through the Proxy server. I have access to proxy server and it certainly supports [UDP](https://github.com/qwj/python-proxy#protocols).

I have researched this in the last few weeks:

- proxycap, proxifier and other alternatives doesn't support UDP and UBUNTU
- I found [this blog](https://blog.pierky.com/sudppipe-a-simple-udp-proxy-port-forwarder/) suggest using `sudppipe` without a very good documentation
- and all the other port forwarder require 2 set of ip:port which I don't understand as I need to rewrite all packets?

so, How this task can be accomplished without VPN services? how do they do it?